# input type number using min and max range bug

Tags: reactjs, input

I made a generator for random number between a range of min and max number.
Now, it looks like there is some kind of a bug that I can't tell if it's in my code or in the input type.
Let's say max = 99 and min = 11, If I use the arrows to make min input go below 10 (making it a one digit number) it's value will jump to 15 (value of max), and if I try to use the arrows to make max a go to 100 (making it a triple digit number), it will jump to 11 (value of min).
What is going on here?

App.js:

```
class Generator extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
        onView: '0',
        minNum: 0 ,
        maxNum: 100
      } 
    }

    btnClick = () => {
      const { minNum, maxNum } = this.state;
      const min = Math.ceil(minNum);
      const max = Math.floor(maxNum);
      const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      return this.setState({ onView : x });
    }

    minRangeInputChange = (event) => {
      const { minNum, maxNum } = this.state;
       if (event.target.value > maxNum) {
        this.setState({ minNum: maxNum });
       } else {
        this.setState({ minNum: event.target.value });
      }
      return console.log(minNum);
    }

    maxRangeInputChange = (event) => {
      const { minNum, maxNum } = this.state;
       if (event.target.value < minNum) {
        this.setState({ maxNum: minNum});
      } else {
        this.setState({ maxNum: event.target.value })
      }
      return console.log(maxNum);
    }

  render() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
    <Instructions />
    <Range 
      max={this.state.maxNum} 
      min={this.state.minNum} 
      minChange={this.minRangeInputChange}
      maxChange={this.maxRangeInputChange}
      />
    <Generate currentClick={this.btnClick}/>
    <View show={this.state.onView}/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Generator;
```

Range component:

```
class Range extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        }
        render() {
    return (
        <div className="range">
            <h3>Minimum</h3>
                <input 
                type="number" 
                min="0"
                max="99999999999999999999"
                value={this.props.min} 
                onChange={this.props.minChange} 
                required/>
            <h3>Maximum</h3>
                <input 
                type="number" 
                min="1"
                max="99999999999999999999"
                value={this.props.max}
                onChange={this.props.maxChange}
                required/>
        </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Range;
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. What are the logs printing?

Comment: The `e.target.value` is a string, you must use `parseInt(e.target.value, 10)` to get the corresponding number, or JavaScript will compare the values as if they were strings, and not numbers.